# TimThumb - Broken Images on WordPress Site, but Only on One Dimension

Tags: wordpress, timthumb

I'm having some problems on a WordPress site I am working on: http://bit.ly/1Hs41z8

TimThumb generates the thumbnails in the bottom section of the site just fine with no issues. However, in the slider, the thumbnail images are broken. When I look at the URL, it looks really long and complex so I am not sure what is causing it to break. If I go to the image url itself, the image loads fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anything in your error log?

Comment: I can take a look. Any idea where I would find it?

Comment: Depends on your system, but probably in /var/log? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log

Answer (score 0):

**TimThumb** is no longer supported or maintained. You can read the reasons why on blog: [TimThumb End of Life.](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2014/09/timthumb-end-life/)

[See what Google say's](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/)

I would suggest you to use [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/).

From **PHPThumb**:

> phpThumb() uses the GD library to create thumbnails from images (JPEG,
>   PNG, GIF, BMP, etc) on the fly. The output size is configurable (can
>   be larger or smaller than the source), and the source may be the
>   entire image or only a portion of the original image. True color and
>   resampling is used if GD v2.0+ is available, otherwise paletted-color
>   and nearest-neighbour resizing is used. ImageMagick is used wherever
>   possible for speed. Basic functionality is available even if GD
>   functions are not installed (as long as ImageMagick is installed). One
>   demo file uses portions of Javascript API by James Austin.

Comment: I'll look into switching but might not be able to before the festival (it's in September). I am using the Wordpress featured image code so I am not sure why TimThumb is activating on the site.

Comment: are you using any plugin ?

Comment: I was able to solve it using the built in WordPress the_post_thumbnail code and swap out the TimThumb code. I still have the timthumb.php file on the server. Should I just delete it?

Comment: it is upto you, if you sure there is no use of timthumb then just delete it.